# Defining a function that uses range of a list inside the function

Tags: python

I am getting an error (in line 1) when running this and I don't know how to fix it. I want a function to go through all of the states in the list, an if it is found, inform the user. Thanks!

```
def find_state(in range(0,len(stateslist)))
    stateslist = [AL, AK, AZ, AR, CA, CO, CT]
    if state == stateslist
    return: "Yes, this state is in the US."

state = input("Input the state ID you are checking. (I.E. CO) ")

print(find_state)
```

Comment: where are you calling find_state?

Comment: There seems to be _some serious misunderstanding_ of syntax here. I suggest [finding a Python book or tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570/what-is-the-best-quick-read-python-book-out-there), reading through it, and then understanding the syntax and core concepts. Don't worry, we've all been through the initial stage of confusion. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
stateslist = ['AL', 'AK', 'AZ', 'AR', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT']

state = input("Input the state ID you are checking. (I.E. CO) ")

if state in stateslist:
  print('Great, it is in!')
else:
  print('No, no such state')
```

**Function form:**

```
def test_state(state):
  return state in ['AL', 'AK', 'AZ', 'AR', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT']

state = input("Input the state ID you are checking. (I.E. CO) ")

if test_state(state):
  print('Great, it is in!')
else:
  print('No, no such state')
```

Comment: my teacher wants it in the form of a function...I solved it this way as well but it wasn't what was wanted

Answer (score 1):

What you're writing is not real python, and you should take a look on basic aspects of the languages, such as writing strings, functions, and loops.

Moreover, you should always account for user issues on writing numbers that can become int/float variables, or writing the text in lower case.

So this is the best solution for you:

```
def find_state(state):
    stateslist = ["AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT"]
    if state.upper() in stateslist:
        return "Yes, this state is in the {}.".format(state.upper())
    return "State not found"

state = find_state(input("Input the state ID you are checking. (I.E. CO) "))
print(state)
```

Comment: If `input()` didn't return a `str`, it will raise an error anyways. (You're thinking about Python 2?) Otherwise `input()` should always return a string.

Comment: @TrebuchetMS, you're right, a little mix with python 2 input(), indeed!
Update in the code to contain only python 3 code here